# Can the STM32F1 used for ST-LINK on the ST discovery boards be used as a normal chip?

Tags: stm32, embedded, st-link

I have a STM32F0 Discovery board. I am hoping to desolder and use the STM32F103C8T6 chip (seen at the top, used for st-link on-chip debugger) for a separate project.

[image: stm23f0 Dev Board]

Would this chip be usable as if it were a normal stm32f1 chip?

Is there any reason that it wouldn't be able to be used for development?
Is there a way I could check?

I haven't been able to find any resources on if this chip might have any permanent configuration.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can use them as a normal chip. You can also desolder them and put a different pin compatible STM32 chip on the dev board (if you need one with more ROM or memory. Or if you accidentally smoke one on the dev board)

There are two on the board one is for the JTAG and the other is the programmed MCU

Answer (score 4):

It's a normal chip.  Generally, one reason you could not reuse a chip is if the external flash access has been permanently disabled.  Some STM32 chips have a feature where external read/write/erase access to flash can be permanently disabled.  But my quick research suggests the STM32F103 does not have this feature.  Read about the "RDP" (read protection) "option byte" in the reference manual for the chip.